# How to extract id param from Backbone Router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a router set up as follows:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "/SomeApp/Scene/:id": "main",
    }

    main: function (sceneId) {
        console.log(sceneId);
    }
});
```

and initialised here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var router = new Router();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

When I visit `http://localhost:12345/SomeApp/Scene/5`, the route from the `routes` object is not matched, and `main()` is not called.

If I create a route with an empty key, eg:

```
routes: {
    "": "main",
}
```

then main() is called, but of course with no parameters.

Could anyone point out what I've misunderstood about how route parameters work, and/or how I should be setting up my routes?

Thanks.

**Edit**

An important point which I should have mentioned initially is that the app is being served from /SomeApp/Scene on the server, not from the root of the site.

Comment: Did you try `"SomeApp/Scene/:id"`?

Comment: @jantimon Yes.  I also tried calling `Backbone.history.start({root: '/SomeApp', pushstate: true});` and changing the route key to just `'Scene/:id'` but this didn't work either.  Admittedly, it was kind of a stab in the dark.

Comment: Use a generic route to easily check what's the format of the route: `'*path': 'display'` and `display: function(path) {alert(path);}`. Then you should be able to configure correctly your root and your routes.

Comment: @Loamhoof Thanks for the idea.  Unfortunately, this results in `path` being `null`.

Comment: Also, am I right in thinking that using `{pushstate: true}` with a pushstate-compatible browser (Chrome in this case) should mean that I don't need to use a `#` in my URLs?  I have tested both with and without, just wondering.

Comment: @Twicetimes yes, that's the goal of the history API. Also, is `path` null with and without the `root` option?

Comment: @Loamhoof Yes, `path` remains null without root and with `root` set to any of `/SomeApp/Scene`, `/SomeApp/Scene/`, `SomeApp/Scene` or `SomeApp/Scene/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are serving from `/SomeApp/Scene` you need to pass that as the `root` param to `Backbone.history`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var router = new Router();
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root:'/SomeApp/Scene/'});
});
```

If you intend not to use the hash (`#`) you should pass `pushState: true` as well otherwise it will not match.

route:

```
routes: {
 ":id": "main",
}
```

The above will match: `http://localhost:12345/SomeApp/Scene/5` with `pushState: true` and `http://localhost:12345/SomeApp/Scene/#5` without it.

Comment: I thought I'd tried every combination of `root` value and route key, but yes, your solution works.  Thanks for clarifying everything.  I think I may also have been typing `pushstate` instead of `pushState` on some attempts, but don't tell anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to include underscore.js before backbone.js? Example here works

http://imstillreallybored.com/bb.html#search/test

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
                routes:{
                    "search/:query": "search"
                },
                search: function(search){
                    alert('search ' + search);
                }
});

var app_router = new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
//app_router.navigate('#search/' + $.trim($(this).val()));
```

Comment: Nope, they're definitely both loaded in the right order (using require.js)

Comment: try not having a slash in the beginning of your route ex:/Someapp/Scene to ex:Someapp/Scene

Comment: I should probably have pointed out that the Backbone app is being served from `/SomeApp/Scene` on the server, not from the root of the site, so I don't want to visit `/#SomeApp/Scene/5`, otherwise it will serve up the site's default index page (which is for something else).  Basically, I just want backbone to be able to retrieve the scene id from the path `SomeApp/Scene/5`.

Comment: Yes, I've tried both with and without the leading slash.  No luck :/